# Using Ref in functional component results in NaN when accessing element height

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, ref

I have a class component that references a canvas element, but when I try to reference the same element in a functional component I am running into issues.

```
class Game extends Component {
    state = {
        circle: {
            x: 50,
            y: 100,
            radius: 20
        }
    }
draw = () => {
        const ctx = this.refs.canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.state.circle.x, this.state.circle.y, this.state.circle.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
componentDidMount() {
        this.draw()
    }
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <canvas ref="canvas" width={450} height={650} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

canvas.height is NaN, and I don't exactly understand why I needed to use .current to access the DOM element.

```
const Game = () => {
  const canvas = useRef(null);
  
  const [circle, setcircle] = useState({
    x: 50,
    y: canvas.height/2,
    radius: 20
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    draw()
  }, []);

  const draw = () => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }


  return (
      <div> 
        <canvas ref={canvas} width={450} height={650} />
      </div>
  );
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 const [circle, setcircle] = useState({
  x: 50,
  // y: canvas.current.height/2,// cannot determine it here, as the commit has not happned
  radius: 20,
});

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  setcircle({
    x: 50,
    y: canvas.current.height / 2,
    radius: 20,
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: That gives the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined`

Comment: Yes you are right , I will not have access to canvas in useState, same as we donot have access to ref in constructor in class based component